# Cannot override default Zend Email error message when using config

Tags: forms, validation, email, zend-framework

Using an ini file to configure a Zend (1.12) Form, I am having an issue trying to override the default email messages. The config looks like:

```
elements.emailAddress.type = email
elements.emailAddress.options.label = "Email Address"
elements.emailAddress.options.required = true
elements.emailAddress.options.maxlength = 255
elements.emailAddress.options.validators.required.validator = NotEmpty
elements.emailAddress.options.validators.required.options.messages.isEmpty = "An email address is required"
elements.emailAddress.options.validators.email.validator = EmailAddress
elements.emailAddress.options.validators.email.options.messages.emailAddressInvalidFormat = "Please enter a valid email address"
...
```

Whilst I am able to override the `isEmpty` message in this manner, the `emailAddressInvalidFormat` message remains the default `"'xxx' is not a valid email address in the basic format local-part@hostname"`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your edit as an answer and accept it rather than appending it to your question.

Comment: Will do, when the system lets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A false negative! I was using an extended library class to add HTML5 form elements (such as email) that added its own email validator that was overriding my configured validator!